# Free app to minify / obfuscate Angulr Js

Tags: gratis, angularjs, obfuscation

I am looking for a gratis app to minify / obfuscate AngularJs, to make it difficult for anyone to copy & edit it.

Please only recommend something which you have personally used, and trust (I know how to Google :-). This is especially important, because minifying / obfuscating AngularJs is not the same as plain JS.

Preferably something which runs under Windows, but I can use a Linux VM if necessary.

I seek a single click solution, which means that I don’t want to have to make manual edits after each change to the code & obfuscation.

It would be helpful if changes to function names in the controller were also made to the HTML of the view. Otherwise, such names should be unmangled.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use npm/Gulp:

```
- package.json
   "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
   "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",

- minify.js

    var gulp = require('gulp'),
        pr = gulp.src(folder + '/**/*')
            .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude('*.min')),
        min = require('gulp-uglify');

    pr.pipe(babel({
        presets: ["es2015"]
    })).pipe(min())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folder + '.min/'));
```

Comment: According to https://www.npmjs.com/pricing the free version only allows me to "Install and publish open source code in the npm Registry" :-(

Comment: But you're not going to sell npm, you just use it for compression. So the license is not valid for you.

Comment: So, I am allowed to use NPM for priavte use? Does that include as an installer for s/w whcih I am develoing?

Comment: Definitely true.

Comment: Hanks Have you actually tested this with AngularJS? Becuase plain JS solutions tend not to work for Angular

Comment: We're actively using it... and not only for AngularJS, but also for other frameworks (as ExtJS)

Comment: I will give it a go this evening. I am interested to see if it updates  the HTML of my views to match the newly obfuscated names of the corresponding `$scope` controller functions